# Ionic V4, JSON works from URL not from MySQL

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm working on an Ionic project who based on API from JSON mysql. When I'm using the XAMPP or localhost url, it doesn't work, but when I copied the files of XAMPP JSON and paste it on Myapi.com, it works correctly.

```
loadData(){
    let data:Observable<any>;
    data = this.http.get('https://localhost/ionicPGL_project/server_api/locations.php');
    data.subscribe(result => {
      this.items = result;
    });
 }
```

These are the errors:

> zone.js:3243 GET https://localhost/ionicPGL_project/server_api/locations.php net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

or

> core.js:15724 ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "https://localhost/ionicPGL_project/server_api/locations.php", ok: false, …}